# C#: Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've made a terrible mistake and deleted Settings.Settings from my project in VS2010.

Is there a possibility to recreate that file? I didn't found anything yet.

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: No source control? Shame shame shame.

Comment: Yep. But I've found the solution: Project --> <Project-Name>-Settings --> Settings --> Create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "recreate" you mean "make a new one":

1. Right-click on the project in the solution explorer,
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select "Settings" on the left
4. Click the link in the center pane that says "This project does not contain a settings file. Click to create one"
5. Enter your settings.

Or, pull a copy from your source control system.

Answer (score 2):

If you Delete anything referencing the Settings you have and Go to the properties of the project and click Settings, it should prompt you to recreate it: [Visual Studio Project: Properties/Settings.settings Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769273/visual-studio-project-properties-settings-settings-missing)